# Problem with routing elements of the list which are reapted than x value

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I have this code written in haskell, and what i'm trying to achive in this code is to input list and a value, and output list of values that are repeated more at least x times in the input list. But the code seems good to me but haskell doesn't agree with me. so it would be nice if someone explained to me why is that so.

```
import Prelude
import Data.List

moreThan a [] = []
moreThan a (x:xs) = moreThan2 a (x:xs) 1
        where moreThan2 a (x:xs) suma
                | null (x:xs) = output
                | x `elem` xs = moreThan2 a (x:delete x xs) (suma+1)
                | suma < a = do
                    moreThan2 a xs 1
                | suma > a = do
                    output ++ x
                    moreThan2 a xs 1
                where
                    output = []


main = print( moreThan 2 [1,2,3,3,4,2,3,5,1,2] )
```

Thats was haskell says about my code:

```
zadanie.hs:23:8: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 18 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: print (moreThan 2 [1, 2, 3, 3, ....])
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main = print (moreThan 2 [1, 2, 3, ....])
   |
23 | main = print( moreThan 2 [1,2,3,3,4,2,3,5,1,2] )
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

zadanie.hs:23:15: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a1’ arising from a use of ‘moreThan’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Eq a1)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a1’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Eq Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
        instance Eq Integer
          -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp-1.0.2.0:GHC.Integer.Type’
        instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Maybe’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 12 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely
        ‘(moreThan 2 [1, 2, 3, 3, ....])’
      In the expression: print (moreThan 2 [1, 2, 3, 3, ....])
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main = print (moreThan 2 [1, 2, 3, ....])
   |
23 | main = print( moreThan 2 [1,2,3,3,4,2,3,5,1,2] )
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

zadanie.hs:23:27: error:
    • No instance for (Num [a1]) arising from the literal ‘1’
    • In the expression: 1
      In the second argument of ‘moreThan’, namely ‘[1, 2, 3, 3, ....]’
      In the first argument of ‘print’, namely
        ‘(moreThan 2 [1, 2, 3, 3, ....])’
   |
23 | main = print( moreThan 2 [1,2,3,3,4,2,3,5,1,2] )
   |  

                     ^
```

Comment: in what way does *Haskell not agree*? Is there an error or is your code not working as expected?

Comment: btw: there are a couple of issues you can see right away: `null (x:xs)` should always be `False` here, there is no *fallback* (what if `suma == a` AND `x` is not in `x`? you don't handle this case, `output` is always `[]` (maybe you'll want to add this as an *accumulator* parameter to `moreThan2`? )

Comment: Here u go i edited the the post and added the error message

Comment: I'm not sure I can see the idea in your code - but there are a couple of syntax/type errors on top (maybe you should rework this step by step) - can you try to explain your algorithm? seems like you want to count up `suma` when you see the head of the list in it's tail - but how does this help? You only count  this exact situation - so the first increase of `suma` might be for an `5` and the next for an `6` but this does not really help you in finding if the `5` is there more than 3 times if I call this with `a=3` does it?

Comment: As far as i understand i can chacnge `null (x:xs)` to null xs and it should help becoues the function will stop as soon as it hits last element. I changed code a bit i will edit it in the post to so there is `suma >= a` but i don;t understand how there can be no `x` in the `x`

Comment: this is how you could do it `moreThan n = map head . filter (\g -> length g >= n) . group . sort` (as I understand your problem) but this is probably homework and you are not allowed to use those functions right?

Comment: What i;m trying to achive here is too for example when i take head of the list, i want to add `+1` to the `suma` when ever i detect a the same number in the tail, but if there is no more number 'which is the head` more example 5 i want to check if there was enough of this numbers in list for me to add it to output if yes, i just add it, if not i just proceed with the tail

Comment: I do can use whatever i want but i haven;t ever heard about group and i need to look this up, and understand what u just typed. But thanks for help so far

Comment: Does the problem statement provide a type signature for the `moreThan` function ? or just states that you have to provide a suitable one ? The choice of type signature can alter the algorithm massively.

Comment: what I was trying to say was that it's not enough to just count occurences and reset - for example if you do this in a list like this: `[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]` and ask for `a >= 2` then you'll not get any elements as you constantly reset your sum - you can fix this with a `sort` first of course if you want

Comment: It looks like you're trying to program in an imperative language, but with Haskell syntax. I would recommend that you review the fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

When GHC barfs up a pile of inscrutible type errors (especially nonsense like `No instance for (Num [a1]) arising from the literal '1'`), it's often helpful to add some type signatures.  What's going on here is that there is a serious typing error in your code (a place where GHC expected a list but you supplied a single number), and GHC is letting its imagination run wild while it tries to figure out what you're trying to do.  A type signature can bring GHC back down to earth.  We don't need the most general type signature at this point, so how about sticking with integers.  Your function should take a count and a list of integers, and return a list of those integers appearing more often than the given count:

```
moreThan :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
moreThan a [] = []
moreThan a (x:xs) = moreThan2 a (x:xs) 1
        where moreThan2 a (x:xs) suma
                | null (x:xs) = output
                | x `elem` xs = moreThan2 a (x:delete x xs) (suma+1)
                | suma < a = do
                    moreThan2 a xs 1
                | suma > a = do
                    output ++ x
                    moreThan2 a xs 1
                where
                    output = []
```

This gives a much more sensible error message:

```
MoreThan.hs:6:34-37: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[a0]’
      Expected type: [[a0]]
        Actual type: [Int]
    • In the second argument of ‘moreThan2’, namely ‘(x : xs)’
      In the expression: moreThan2 a (x : xs) 1
      In an equation for ‘moreThan’:
          moreThan a (x : xs)
            = moreThan2 a (x : xs) 1
            where
                moreThan2 a (x : xs) suma
                  | null (x : xs) = output
                  | x `elem` xs = moreThan2 a (x : delete x xs) (suma + 1)
                  | suma < a = do moreThan2 a xs 1
                  | suma > a
                  = do output ++ x
                       ....
                  where
                      output = []
  |
6 | moreThan a (x:xs) = moreThan2 a (x:xs) 1
  |                                  ^^^^
```

and we can pin things down even further by adding a type signature for the helper function `moreThan2`:

```
moreThan :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
moreThan a [] = []
moreThan a (x:xs) = moreThan2 a (x:xs) 1
        where moreThan2 :: Int -> [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
              moreThan2 a (x:xs) suma
                | null (x:xs) = output
                | x `elem` xs = moreThan2 a (x:delete x xs) (suma+1)
                | suma < a = do
                    moreThan2 a xs 1
                | suma > a = do
                    output ++ x
                    moreThan2 a xs 1
                where
                    output = []
```

giving the error:

```
MoreThan.hs:14:31: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘x’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: output ++ x
      In the expression:
        do output ++ x
           moreThan2 a xs 1
   |
14 |                     output ++ x
   |                               ^
```

Well, there's the problem.  If you want to add a single element `x` to the end of the list, you need to write:

```
output ++ [x]
```

After that fix, it type checks, though your example throws a runtime error:

```
λ> main
*** Exception: MoreThan.hs:(8,15)-(17,31): Non-exhaustive patterns in function moreThan2
```

Looking more carefully at your algorithm, you're doing a number of things wrong here.  First, you're trying to use `output` as a sort of mutable variable that `moreThan2` will "remember" through recursive calls.  But, when you write:

```
moreThan2 a (x:xs) suma
  | null (x:xs) = output
  | x `elem` xs = moreThan2 a (x:delete x xs) (suma+1)
  | suma < a = do
      moreThan2 a xs 1
  | suma > a = do
      output ++ [x]
      moreThan2 a xs 1
  where
      output = []
```

the uses of `output` are all just synonyms for `[]`, so it's exactly equivalent to:

```
moreThan2 a (x:xs) suma
  | null (x:xs) = []
  | x `elem` xs = moreThan2 a (x:delete x xs) (suma+1)
  | suma < a = do
      moreThan2 a xs 1
  | suma > a = do
      [] ++ [x]             -- <== output is always []
      moreThan2 a xs 1
```

which obviously isn't what you wanted.  Second, the `do`-block:

```
do output ++ [x]
   moreThan2 a xs 1
```

is definitely not doing what you think it is.  Technically, it's using the list monad, and it creates a list consisting of repeated copies of `moreThan2 a xs 1` repeated a number of times equal to the length of the list `output ++ [x]`.  In other words, it's equivalent to:

```
concat (replicate (length (output ++ [x])) (moreThan2 a xs 1))
```

In your case, since `output` is just `[]`, the calculated length is 1, so it all reduces down to:

```
moreThan2 a xs 1
```

and the `output ++ [x]` is effectively ignored.

So, instead of doing this weird do-block thing, you either want to pass the accumulating output along as another argument:

```
moreThan2 a (x:xs) suma output
  | null (x:xs) = output
  | x `elem` xs = moreThan2 a (x:delete x xs) (suma+1) output
  | suma < a = moreThan2 a xs 1 output
  | suma > a = moreThan2 a xs 1 (output ++ [x])
```

or just use the output of the recursive call directly:

```
moreThan2 a (x:xs) suma
  | null (x:xs) = []
  | x `elem` xs = moreThan2 a (x:delete x xs) (suma+1)
  | suma < a = moreThan2 a xs 1
  | suma > a = moreThan2 a xs 1 ++ [x]   -- <== just use directly
```

Second, and the thing that's causing the runtime error, when you write:

```
moreThan2 a (x:xs) suma | ... = ...
```

this definition will only ever be used if the arguments match the pattern on the left, and `x:xs` only ever matches a non-empty list.  So, the code:

```
moreThan2 a (x:xs) suma | null (x:xs) = ...
```

won't work to handle the case where the second argument is empty because it's too late to check after the pattern on the left has matched.  You need to split up the cases the same way you did for `moreThan` using:

```
moreThan2 a [] suma = ...
moreThan2 a (x:xs) suma = ...
```

to get something more like this:

```
moreThan2 a [] suma = []
moreThan2 a (x:xs) suma
  | x `elem` xs = moreThan2 a (x:delete x xs) (suma+1)
  | suma < a = moreThan2 a xs 1
  | suma > a = moreThan2 a xs 1 ++ [x]
```

That will still give a runtime error, but now it's because you're handling the case where `suma` is less than `a` and the case where it's greater, but not the case where it's equal.  Fixing that gives a final version that appears to work:

```
moreThan :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
moreThan a [] = []
moreThan a (x:xs) = moreThan2 a (x:xs) 1
        where moreThan2 :: Int -> [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
              moreThan2 a [] suma = []
              moreThan2 a (x:xs) suma
                | x `elem` xs = moreThan2 a (x:delete x xs) (suma+1)
                | suma <= a = moreThan2 a xs 1
                | suma > a = moreThan2 a xs 1 ++ [x]
```

You can drop or generalize the type signature at this point.  Also, you can get rid of the empty list check in `moreThan`, since `moreThan2` is already doing it.  This gives:

```
moreThan :: Eq a => Int -> [a] -> [a]
moreThan a xs = moreThan2 a xs 1
        where moreThan2 a [] suma = []
              moreThan2 a (x:xs) suma
                | x `elem` xs = moreThan2 a (x:delete x xs) (suma+1)
                | suma <= a = moreThan2 a xs 1
                | suma > a = moreThan2 a xs 1 ++ [x]
```

Answer (score 0):

an possible way is :

```
import Data.List

moreThan n xs = nub $ concat [ x | x <- ( group(sort(xs))), length x >= n ]
```

I think it's straightforward ... , you should not thinking in imperative way ...

so that said, the way of thinking is

first of all, sort the array

```
sort [1,2,3,3,4,2,3,5,1,2]

[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5]
```

second, group identical numbers

```
group [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5]

[[1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4],[5]]
```

with list comprehension, select all which length is greater than 'n'

```
[ x | x <- [[1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4],[5]] , length x >= 2 ]

[[1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
```

at last, concat the resulting array

```
concat [[1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]

[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
```

finally

```
nub  [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]

[1,2,3]
```

Comment: you forgot the `map head` before the `concat`, perhaps.

Comment: @WillNess , i don't follow you ... why using map and head ? could you be more precise ?  "input list and a value, and output list of values that are repeated more at least x times in the input list"

Comment: aahhh!!! i got !, but is not said , unique list of numbers, lol  !!!   , "nub" your's best friend ! ! , fixed !